Select with initial value not emitting initial valueChanges event
I have a Select component where the desired behavior is:

the options are fetched from a service
the component should have the first option pre-selected
every value change event should result in a data fetch, including the first pre-selection

The template looks like
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="selectOption">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (options$ | async)" [value]="option.value">
      {{option.displayName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
  <!-- some charts and other components -->
</div>

then the component looks like
interface Option {
  value: number,
  displayName: string
}

@Component()
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly selectOption: FormControl<Option>;
  readonly options$: Observable<Option[]>;
  readonly data$: Observable<Data>;

  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
    this.options$ = this.dataService.listOptions();

    this.selectOption = new FormControl<Option>(DEFAULT_OPTION);

    this.data = this.getData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options$.subscribe((options) => {
      if (options.length > 0) {
        this.selectOption.setValue(options[0]);
      }
    }
  }

  private getData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.selectOption.valueChanges.pipe(
      switchMap((value) => this.dataService.queryData(value))
    );
  }
}

So following my stated goals above, what I would like to see is for example dataService.listOptions() produces
[
  {value: 1, displayName: "First"},
  {value: 2, displayName: "Second"},
]

which then pre-selects 1 and displays "First" in the Select component, which finally makes a call to this.dataService.queryData(1). Then from the UI if the user changes the selection to 2 then this.dataService.queryData(2) is called, and so on.
When I run this in development it seems to achieve my stated goals above. However in my unit tests several fail, with the common cause being that getData() never seems to be called, seemingly because this.selectOption.valueChanges never emits. I would think that the snippet in ngOnInit would trigger this valueChanges event.
I also tried moving this initial value setting to ngAfterViewInit but this results in a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.
The fact that this works in a local environment but fails during unit testing makes me think this is some kind of Angular lifecycle issue, and I have some initialization too early or otherwise at the wrong time. Can anyone identify an issue with this general approach? Or why this may fail while unit testing? I apologize I have not been able to create an MCVE, but hopefully the above example demonstrates the overall approach.

What does your unit test look like ? Do you trigger ngOnInit manually in your test ?

Your subscribe to the value changes event occurs in the template, so it is possible you have a race condition where the options observable completes before the value change subscribes.

@robbieAreBest thanks for that suggestion, that certainly could be possible! If that were the case, what do you suggest refactoring to ensure the order is deterministic? Is there a better lifecycle hook to move the subscribe?

@CoryKramer I'm on mobile at the moment so can't answer with an example, but one thing you could have the value changes update the value of a BehaviorSubject. Then, apply a switchMap to the BehaviorSubject where you retrieve your data based on last value. You will probably want to filter for null/undefined as well

@robbieAreBest Genius, thank you :) That was exactly the fix
